# Can't Display All Records In Laravel Pivot Table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have a Players / Lessonhours pivot table that is saving all of the values passed to it from a form. In my view however, it only shows some of the records associated. It seems I am having a problem when I do a $players->lessonhour->toArray. When I do $lessonhours->players->toArray(), I only get some of the records. I can't see what I am doing wrong in the relationship setup. Something obviously needs tewaking. Can anyone help?

Tinker:

[image: Tinker view]

MySql:

[image: MySql view]

Player Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Collective\Html\Eloquent\FormAccessible;
use Carbon\Carbon;


class Players extends Model
{
    public $table = "players";

    protected $fillable = array('fname', 'lname', 'gender', 'birthdate');


    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'users_id');
    }

    public function lessonhours()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Lessonhours', 'lessonhour_player',    'lessonhours_id', 'players_id');
    }

    public function getFullName($id)
    {
        return ucfirst($this->fname ) . ' ' . ucfirst($this->lname);
    }

   protected $dates = ['birthdate'];

    public function setBirthdateAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['birthdate'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y',   $value);
    }
}


Lessonhours Model:

     <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use Collective\Html\Eloquent\FormAccessible;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Lessonhours extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('signup_date', 'players_id', 'packages_id');

    public $table = "lessonhours";

    public function players()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Players', 'lessonhour_player',  'lessonhours_id', 'players_id');
    }

    public function packages()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Packages', 'packages_id');
     }

    public function hoursused()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Hoursused', 'lessonhours_id');
    }

    protected $dates = ['signup_date'];

    public function setSignUpDateAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['signup_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y',     $value);
    }
}
```

This is what the view shows. Everyone on the list should have at least 1 package, some have 2.

[image: Player List]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Players model swap `lessonhours_id` and `players_id`:

```
public function lessonhours()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Lessonhours', 'lessonhour_player', 'players_id', 'lessonhours_id');
        }
```

Comment: Yeah, by inverting these you were looking up the wrong lesson hour record. Are you using foreign key constraints on your pivot table? That can help prevent this sort of thing when the number of players is way higher than the number of lesson hours (because it's just luck that the wrong lessonhour_id corresponded to an existing player_id).

Comment: That worked. I am still unable to access the properties of the Players table. I didn't mention in the original question as I thought the issues were (excuse the pun) RELATED.. 
$lessonhours->players->fname etc... produce an undefined property error. Should I approach this as a different question?

Comment: @CarterFort I do have constraints defined in the db schema. Thanks.

Comment: if I get you right: `$lessonhours->players` gives you a collection. To get properties of players you should loop trhough them.

Comment: Right, that's a collection. If you wanted to get all the `fname` values back in a collection, you could use the `map()` or `only()` methods on the collection: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-collections#available-methods

Comment: Also you're probably going to want to eager load the player relationship so you're not hitting the DB over and over again:https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Yes, that does the trick. In this case better than I expected because I was wondering how to show both partners in a semi-private lesson and all players in group lessons.

Comment: @CarterFort Thank you for the advice on eager loading. Guys, Is there some way to discuss the topic away from this question?